# Use PHP as ODBC provider?

Tags: php, odbc

I got a proprietary business software that can use ODBC as datasource to retrieve order data by order_id.
The data to be fetched is however distributed over different data sources (MySQL, JavaDB) and would need processing before passing it on to the software. Unfortunately it also needs to be very fast which disqualifies preprocessing and saving it into MySQL which has an ODBC.

Hence I am looking for a way to implement an ODBC provider preferably in PHP?

Any suggestions where to look?

Paul

Comment: you'd probably find implementing this in php would be even slower. php is not "native" code - you'd have to hook into the COM system, which has its own overhead as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PHP PDO
With pdo you can connect with odbc, mysql, oracle, etc
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I am not looking into how to query data sources with PHP but how to do a ODBC provider (ideally through PHP)